# Dynamic Expression API: I can do a predicate, how to code an OrderBy Specification?

Tags: c#, lambda, repository, dynamic-linq, specification-pattern

I figured out how to do a predicate from a string supplied by a client based on [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) (this is wrapped in a Specification object):

```
return System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<TE, bool> 
       (filter.ToString(), arguments.ToArray())
```

where filter is a string of expression language as described in their help file.  Works like a charm.

**However, is it possible to translate a string list of orderby fields into a strongly typed expression like this:**

```
Expression<Func<E, object>> orderby
```

Notes:

Here's my repository method to filter and order items

```
public IList<E> Get(Expression<Func<E, bool>>   filterLambda = null,
                    Expression<Func<E, object>> orderbyLambda = null,
                    int? page = null, 
                    int? pageSize = null)
```

I would like to call it using:

```
var a = Repo.Get( filterLambda:  Specification.Where(   StringListOfFilters),
                  orderbyLambda: Specification.OrderBy( StringListOfOrderBy),
                  page: 1,
                  pageSize: 100 );
```

Any ideas on how to convert a string list of OrderBy fields into a strongly typed lambda expression?  Examples of the strings would be:

```
fieldname
fieldname descending
```

Another note:

I am translating the strings coming from the client, which are `fieldname op value` validating them with Regex to prevent injection.  Also, I am only referencing Dynamic Linq in the Specification object, not the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a problem anymore.. however it looks like your solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667813/dynamically-create-lambdas-expressions-linq-orderbydescending).